# Searching through a nested array and displaying data

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP script and from a database I am retrieving an array (like the one below)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Server] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 100000
                    [ip_address] => 127.0.0.1
                )

        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Server] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 100001
                    [ip_address] => 127.0.0.2
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [Server] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 100007
                    [ip_address] => 127.0.0.3
                )
        )
)
```

Now I need to search through this nested array (I don't see a way to differently display the array), find a certain 'id' and then display the IP address associated with it.

How do I do that in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new array indexed on the id:

```
$new=[];
foreach($arr as $element){
    $id = $element['server']['id'];
    $new[$id] = $element['server']['ip_address'];
}
```

Then you can access any ip_address by using the id key:

```
echo $new['100007'];
echo $new['100001'];
etc
```

Comment: Thanx! That did the trick for me. Did not think of this approach :$